# how to search value from a list into a pandas dataframe? where list contain multiple string values

Tags: python, pandas, csv

1. I am collecting user input multiple IPs into a list,
2. I want to search any of that IP is present inside a data-frame, any columns.
3. If present output the row values, there can be multiple rows.
4. I already created dataframe and list

   ```
   list = []

   number = int(input("how many value you want in a list: "))

   for i in range(0, number): 

      x =(input("enter values:"))

      list.insert(i,x)

      print(list)

   dx = df1[df1.apply(lambda r: r.str.contains([list], case=False).any(), axis=1)]
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use df.loc() and isin() represented below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create list of IPs (your input from stdin)
ip_list = ['192.168.36.121', '192.168.36.122']

# Create some data for dataframe with some garbage also (you already have)
d = {'item_id': [1, 2, 3], 
 'ip': ['192.168.36.121', '192.168.36.120', '192.168.36.123'], 
 'visit_date': ['2019.03.23', '2019.03.24', '2019.03.25'],
 'trash': ['192.168.36.122', 'abcd', 'efgh']
 }

# Construct dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Return the matching rows only (this is what you need)
mask = np.column_stack([df[col].isin(ip_list) for col in df])
result_rows = df.loc[mask.any(axis=1)]
```

In this case the input list values are found and the corresponding rows are extracted from the whole DataFrame. IP addresses present in multiple columns in the same row are returned only once.